# Determining if a bag of wheat cent pennies has been searched - using statistics.

Tags: robust-statistics

I have collected a sample of 5000 wheat cent pennies, and recorded the number of each year and mint mark $\in \{P, D, S\}$. I have also found out how many wheat cent pennies were minted at each mint, during each year.

What would the formula be to determine if I have more of the common coins - the less valuable (i.e. more of that coin was minted) than would be expected, based on the number minted of one year & mint mark / total of all wheat cents minted?

Would it just be a straight independent probability of each coin based on sample size of 5000?

Comment: You might consider a [Chi-squared test for categorical data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Example_chi-squared_test_for_categorical_data), a.k.a. a "contingency table".